# BLE Device Watcher in UWP

Tags: uwp, bluetooth-lowenergy, listener, desktop

**How to identify update listener of Device Watcher called for which purpose inside update listener handeler event ?**
basically Device Watcher has 3 listener add,update,and remove
when master device discover any slave device add listener has been called 
when slave device going out of range remove listener has been called 
now if device is paired and going out of range it called update listener 
in case of device is paired and made any changes in device it's called update listener so,
inside the update listener i can not able to identify if device is going out of range or coming into range.

my requirement is to first discover 11 ble slave device 
than connect 11 ble slave device to master device
after that send signals to perform different functionality like blink ,flash , vibrate

i connect device by using Pairing.PairAsync() gatt service
after calling this service send 1 signal to device for ble device board setup

during communicate between master and slave device connection continue break so,
i need to auto connect them. when connection broken update listener called so the thing is in all situation like device goes out of range or coming in range ,
and also connect and disconnect time same update listener call. as i said i'm not able to identify inside update listener which purpose listener has called.

here i'm using 
slave device = adafruit bluefruit feather 32u4 board as a slave device 
master device = iball compbook -> which has Bluetooth 4.0

note:
all ble device are working fine which is tested by ios app to

Comment: Please reformat your question. The text section is too long, no one will spent reading everything.

Comment: And what is your specific question?